# expandable list with multi sub lists

Tags: android, listview, github, expandablelistview

I used [this github project](https://github.com/aaironman/SlideExpandListView) but I want to add different sub list for each item of expandable list. What should I do? where should put my data for sub lists??

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.single_expandable_list);
    ActionSlideExpandableListView list = (ActionSlideExpandableListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list);

    // fill the list with data
    list.setAdapter(buildDummyData());

    list.setItemActionListener(new OnActionClickListener() {...});
```